# How to read a text file and return it as a JSON object in Node JS?

Tags: json, node.js, fs

I have a text file. I need to read the file inside a function and return it as a JSON object. The following is throwing an error "Unexpected token V in JSON at position 0" .

**Server.js**

```
fs.readfile('result.txt', 'utf8', function(err,data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(obj);
});
```

result.txt looks like the following

VO1: 10 5 2

VO2: 5 3 2

I think I cannot use JSON.parse directly. How do I proceed?

Comment: What's the content of result.txt?

Comment: Would be helpful to take a look at result.txt.

Comment: You can't, since the `.txt` file gets imported as a string, iirc. You'll have to write your own parser for the data to be translated to json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the following:

> Every line is separated by a newline character (`\n`)
>
> Every line is separated by a `:` where the part in front of it is the key and the part behind it is a   (space) separated string that should indicate the keys values as an array.

Below should work for your format:

```
fs.readfile('result.txt', 'utf8', function(err,data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    let obj = {};
    let splitted = data.toString().split("\n");
    for (let i = 0; i<splitted.length; i++) {
        let splitLine = splitted[i].split(":");
        obj[splitLine[0]] = splitLine[1].trim();
    }
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error with splitLine as unidentified identifier.

Comment: So some of the lines don't have a key, a value or a `:`. Try to add a check before you assign the values to the object @Bharg

Answer (score 2):

It could be issue with `UTF-8` string format, Tried below code and it works

```js
const resultBuffer = fs.readFileSync('result.txt');
const resultData = JSON.parse(resultBuffer.toString().trim());
```

Comment: It’s an issue with the file *not being JSON* or even remotely like JSON.

Comment: My text file was JSON and this creates a valid JSON object of that text file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Baao for providing that answer.

As another flavor of solution, if you don't have any ":" for perhaps a list of files you could always code in a key like so:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(pathAndFilename);
var testData = {};
var splitList = data.toString().split('\r\n');
for (var i = 0; i < splitList.length; i++) {
     testData['fileNumber' + i.toString()] = splitList[i];
}
```

Comment: Hello, what is the pathAndFilename value?

Comment: This would be the full path and file name to the file that you want to read. aka C:\Program Files\MyApp\Configuration\systemConfiguration.txt

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse the text file by yourself. You can use RegExp or some other means to extract the values, create an object out of that and then `JSON.stringify` it.

Answer (score -1):

improving upon @baao answer:

```
const fs = require("fs")

fs.readFile('.czrc', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        throw "unable to read .czrc file.";
    }
   const obj = JSON.parse(data)
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Your result.txt is not valid json.

Valid json would look like this.

```
{
  "VO1": [10, 5, 2],
  "VO2": [5, 3, 2]
}
```