# How to read a text file into an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble finding the best way to tackle my problem. I would like to read a text file into an array of objects. The format of the array is fixed, but if there is a format for the text file that would be better, then that is possible.

The text file I currently have has the following structure:

```
item_tag = milk
item_date = 2020-10-25
item_quantity = 1
*
item_tag = egg
item_date = 2020-10-04
item_quantity = 3
*
item_tag = banana
item_date = 2020-10-03
item_quantity = 2
*
item_tag = apple
item_date = 2020-10-10
item_quantity = 1
*
item_tag = yoghurt
item_date = 2020-10-31
item_quantity = 5
*
```

Each object has three properties and each object is separated by an *. Again, this is a format that I thought could be useful, but I'm open to suggestions.

I would like to turn it into an array structured like this:

```
let Inventory = [
    {"item_name": "milk", "item_date": "2020-10-25", "item_quantity": 1},
    {"item_name": "egg", "item_date": "2020-10-04", "item_quantity": 3},
    {"item_name": "banana", "item_date": "2020-10-03", "item_quantity": 2},
    {"item_name": "apple", "item_date": "2020-10-10", "item_quantity": 1},
    {"item_name": "yoghurt", "item_date": "2020-10-31", "item_quantity": 5}
];
```

I have seen other questions like this (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857458/reading-local-text-file-into-a-javascript-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450961/how-to-read-a-text-file-and-return-it-as-a-json-object-in-node-js)), but these are not for an array of objects. These solutions also both use Node.JS, I would prefer not to use Node unless it's necessary. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30454523/12240995), where another method is used without Node. I am able to display the text using this code from that thread:

```
document.getElementById('inputfile').addEventListener('change', function() { 
  
var fr = new FileReader(); 
fr.onload = function(){ 
    document.getElementById('output') 
            .textContent=fr.result; 
} 
fr.readAsText(this.files[0]); 
})
```

If possible, how could I modify this to turn the text into an array of objects?

Thanks for any help!

On a side note, is it also possible to turn the array (now modified) back into a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with spliting the lines with `.split("\r\n")` and then add the objects using `shift()` to pop out the lines until the array emptied. The code snippet produces the below array:

```
[
  {
    "tag": "milk",
    "date": "2020-10-25",
    "quantity": "1"
  },
  {
    "tag": "egg",
    "date": "2020-10-04",
    "quantity": "3"
  },
  {
    "tag": "banana",
    "date": "2020-10-03",
    "quantity": "2"
  },
  {
    "tag": "apple",
    "date": "2020-10-10",
    "quantity": "1"
  },
  {
    "tag": "yoghurt",
    "date": "2020-10-31",
    "quantity": "5"
  }
]
```

```js
document.getElementById('inputfile').addEventListener('change', function() { 
  var fr = new FileReader(); 
  fr.onload = function(e){ 
    var res = []; 
    var lines = this.result.split("\r\n");
    while(lines.length > 0){      
      res.push({
        tag: getField(lines),
        date: getField(lines),
        quantity: getField(lines),
      });
      if(lines[0] == '*') lines.shift();
    }
    console.log(res);
  } 
  fr.readAsText(this.files[0]); 
})

function getField(lines){
  return lines.shift().split(' = ')[1];
}
```

```html
<input id="inputfile" type="file" value="upload" />
```